# asp.net web api - Sanitizing Input Strings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

Current method is a post operation, constructs a command and puts it on the bus. The part I do not like is **ModelHelper.Trim** see below.

```
[ValidationActionFilter]
public void Post([FromBody]CompanyFormModel company)
{
    var newCompany = new NewCompany
    {
       Id = id,
       Name = ModelHelper.Trim(company.Name),
       Description = ModelHelper.Trim(company.Description),
       Sector = ModelHelper.Trim(company.Sector),
    };

    _bus.Send(newCompany);
}
```

The **ModelHelper.Trim** is checking if the field is string and if not null do a trim.
There is any way that can apply this as a gross cutting concern for all the posts and puts.

Tried to register a TrimmingConverter in Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters ... but does not seem to work.

Any idea how to solve this in a non intrusive way?

Comment: The link you provided is for MVC I need for WebApi

Comment: Here you do not have DefaultModelBinder

Comment: Adding a converter to JsonFormatter does work. maybe the content-type of the request is not json

Comment: the content-type is json

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you are using `DataContractJsonSerializer` instead of JSON.net?

Remove this line if it exist (or set it to false):

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
```

Adding a converter to JsonFormatter does work. Here is mine:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new TrimmingConverter());

        ...
```

The TrimmingConverter

```
public class TrimmingConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var text = (string)reader.Value;
        return text != null ? text.Trim() : null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach works great, but only if you're posting JSON to the Web Api service like $.ajax({contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"....});

Form/XML encoded data and/or retrieving values out of the query string/headers will not be trimmed.